# Convert CSV data to Polygons in Mapinfo

Tags: convert, mapinfo, csv

I've received a CSV file exported from an unknown application containing polygon coordinates in the following format:

Title | Latitude 1 | Longitude 1 | Latitude 2 | Longitude 2 | ... | Latitude 50 | Longitude 50

How can I generate polygons from this data in Mapinfo Professional (12.0)?

Comment: You can solve it with little MapBasic script. Similar method is already explained here: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/23114/creating-polygons-from-points-in-mapinfo